# UIImagePickerController stream type used to append .MOV?

Tags: ios, video, stream, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturemoviefileoutput

## What stream is employed in iOS7 by AVCaptureMovieFileOutput in a UIImagePickerController to append video frames from the camera to it's temporary .MOV file?

A .MOV file is created in a temporary location, and then further appended to by an underlying AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object, when a user is recording a video via a presented UIImagePickerController in iOS7.

---

I've attempted to use symbolic breakpoints and method swizzling in order to pinpoint one of the following (but with no success). It's possible I've missed the one stream type or class that is actually being used (or that my breakpoints are setup incorrectly):

- NSWriteStream
- CFWriteStream
- subclassed NSStream
- fstream
- ofstream
- ostream
- iostream
- NSFileHandle
- posix file descriptor
- AVAssetWriter
- AVAssertExportSession
- ALAssetClass
- ALAssetLibrary

This is what I am using to present the UIImagePickerViewController to record video:

```
    #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

    -(void)startPicker{
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [picker setAllowsEditing:NO];
        [picker setDelegate:self];
        [picker setMediaTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        if (info)
        {
           NSURL* fileURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
           NSLog(@"%@", fileURL.path);
        }
    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

I really need the specific stream type and a way that I can prove for myself that it is being used by iOS7. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A way you can prove? I am not sure, but Apple favors m3u8 for streaming

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly another method to consider but I'm unsure that Apple are employing this technique in this instance. Although your answer is insightful I don't feel it quite fulfils the bounty requirements. I will certainly put some thought into how I can prove they are using this to stream to a .mov file.